# Is possible to use QtConcurrent with Ruby (mingw-32)?

Tags: ruby, windows, qt, qt4, qtconcurrent

How can I use the QtConcurrent Qt module in Ruby?
I'm developing a small app that uses Qt (through the qtbindings binary gem) in Windows (Ruby 1.9.3 mingw-32) but I couldn't find a way to use threads (or use simple concurrent methods calls).
Any help and any example would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that its no different than PyQt4, where QtConcurrent is not available because they can't easily wrap it. If its not being built with your Ruby bindings, its probably not available. You would need to stick to QThread and its siblings.